# I can't access to jobhistoryserver web

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i've a virtual machine with a pseudo distributed hadoop instance (version 3.2.0). I've problem accessing from host to JobHistoryServer web (master-1:19888).

In my host machine the etc/hosts:

```
...
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   msi
192.168.1.107  master-1
...
```

**At the virtual machine**

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
  <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
```

I run the hdfs, yarn and historyserver process:
[image: process and port 19888]

From host machine I view other web ui of hadoop virtual machine instance, but no the historyserver web.

How can I research this issue?

others web:
[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE march 4, 2020**

I think we have any problem with ip routing in my virtual machine, here the virtual machine hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost master-1
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Whit this host file, this is the result of -ls command from my virtual machine

[image]

But the wrong access are to known ip's 
[image]

Maybe this is related to the access error to port 19888. What do you think?

As you can see I'm not an expert in networking.
Thank for your help.

Comment: BTW, remove 127.0.1.1 from your hosts, as per Hadoop setup docs

Comment: Also, each process has log files. Please refer to them

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for ip advertising, i've removed 127.0.1.1.

Comment: Ther problem remains. When i launch a map-reduce job, in the information show `Starting Job = job_1582884480249_0002, Tracking URL = http://master-1:8088/proxy/application_1582884480249_0002/`, if I access to this url the url change to **http://master-1:19888/jobhistory/job/job_1582884480249_0002** and this is not available. @cricket_007 thanks for your reply.

Comment: My first suggestion is from Hadoop installation guide, not a solution to your problem. But yeah, you'll need to make that host/port available for you to access via a port forward in the VM

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't know exactly what port forward I must to include and I don't know why the other ports is running ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've problem accessing from host to JobHistoryServer web (master-1:19888).

You've shown JPS as running the history server, so it's up.

If you can curl it from within the VM and get html response, it's good.

The next step would be to open your VM networking settings and make host port 19888 access the guest port 19888.

Then you can access localhost:19888 from your host web browser

Regarding hdfs command, you don't need to use any host and port if `hdfs dfs -ls /` shows you expected results

The address is automatically taken from the `fs.defaultFS` property

---

Also, it seems like you put the VM on the host-only network of the 192.168.1.X subnet? This isn't necessarily an issue, but just something to be aware of

Comment: You show me the way, within the VM I can curl to port 19888, and from host I can't. What was the problem?: **the firewall!!**, the port was closed.
Thank you for yours explanations, they are been very usefull.